# Forcing credentials when connecting to a network share

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, share-credentials

I am helping a friend diagnose a problem.

He has a Synology NAS box that has a user account with read/write access, and a guest account with read-only access.  The user account on his Win7 laptop matches the one on the NAS box, so that "just works".  The user account on his Win7 media center PC, however, does not match the NAS box.  When he connects to it, he has read-only permission.  When connecting to the NAS box, it doesn't even prompt for credentials - it just goes straight to "guest".  How do you manually set the permissions when connecting?

jorj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take away guest access and actually made a separate account with read only permissions that isn't the built-in guest. When connecting, you will have to use the alternate credentials to connect to the share.

Answer (score 0):

Your friend may have more success if he maps a network share using `net use` combined with switches. If it works he can either set it as a persistent mapping or just call it via startup script (or a more lo-fi entry in the Startup menu if it's just for one machine).

There's a guide (with, for once, some quite helpful examples) at http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_use.mspx?mfr=true. What I think is probably the most useful:

> To connect the user identifier *Dan* as if the connection were made from the *Accounts* domain, type:
>   `net use d: \\server\share /user:Accounts\Dan`

HTH!
Chris

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I ended up just removing the guest account from the server, but this is a valid approach as well.